# File Scrubber in Python 3.6: Is it possible?

Tags: python, windows, file-io, hard-drive, python-3.6

Files do persist on-disk after being "Deleted" or "Permanently Deleted."  Some may not want a file to persist.  To that end, I've written this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from os.path import isfile, getsize
from os import remove
from secrets import randbits
from math import floor

filename: str
while True :
    filename = input('File: ')
    if filename.lower().strip() in ('', 'none', 'quit') :
        exit()
    elif isfile(filename.strip()) :
        filename = filename.strip()
        print()
        break
    else :
        print('\a')

iterations: int
while True :
    try :
        iterations = int(input('Number of iterations: ').strip())
        assert iterations > 0
        break
    except :
        print('\a')

file_size: int
try :
    file_size = getsize(filename)
except :
    print('No access.')
    exit()

for x in range(iterations) :
    y = floor(x / iterations * 100)
    print(f"{y:>02}%\r", end='')
    try :
        file = open(filename, 'wb+')
        file.write(bytes(randbits(8) for _ in range(file_size)))
    except :
        print('Access interrupted on {}%.'.format(y) if x else 'No access.')
        exit()
    finally :
        try :
            file.close()
        except NameError :
            pass

try :
    file = open(filename, 'rb')
    read = file.readall()
    file.close()
    #
    file = open(filename, 'wb+')
    file.write(bytes(randbits(8) ^ read[x] for x in range(file_size)))
    file.close()
    #
    remove(filename)
except :
    print('No access.')
    exit()
finally :
    try :
        if not file.closed : file.close()
    except :
        pass

print('Done.')
```

Have caution, this may be a *black art*.  I use direct-disk-access in write-binary mode to first override a file on-disk with crypto-random bytes for some number of times and then to XOR the resulting file with one more serving of random bytes, and finally I delete the file.

**My question is**: Does the "wb+" write directly over the contents in the physical location of the physical disk allocated for a file?

Comment: If there is relevant code, include it in the question itself, not as a link, and make sure it's a [mcve].

Comment: Ok. I will post my code inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the "wb+" write directly over the contents in the physical location of the physical disk allocated for a file?

No, on multiple levels.

Almost every operating system currently in use has cache mechanisms for disk reads and writes to improve speed. So it might take a while for data to be actually sent to the disk.
On some operating systems [including ms-windows](https://support.microsoft.com/nl-nl/help/324805/how-to-manually-turn-disk-write-caching-on-or-off) you can disable the write cache, but *write performance will suffer considerably*.

Additionally, most modern harddrives have a built-in cache as well. This is controlled by the device's firmware and invisible to the OS. So even it the command from the OS telling the drive to write something returns, this does not guarantee that the write has actually been done.

Also there should be *backups* of the file in question somewhere. You'd have to find and wipe those as well.

---

As an aside, on a modern harddrive it is probably sufficient to overwrite the file with zeros once. See the wikipedia article on [data remanence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_remanence#Feasibility_of_recovering_overwritten_data).

Answer (score 0):

> When working with a file object, does the "wb+" mode write directly over the contents in the physical location of the physical disk allocated for a file?

In POSIX, it's not guaranteed for an arbitrary filesystem. It may work for some fixed implementation with some fixed mount options, though.

See for example [`shred(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/shred.1.html):

> **CAUTION:** Note that shred relies on a very important assumption: that
>          the file system overwrites data in place.  This is the traditional
>          way to do things, but many modern file system designs do not satisfy
>          this assumption.  The following are examples of file systems on which
>          shred is not effective, or is not guaranteed to be effective in all
>          file system modes:
>
> - log-structured or journaled file systems, such as those supplied
>        with AIX and Solaris (and JFS, ReiserFS, XFS, Ext3, etc.)
> - file systems that write redundant data and carry on even if some
>        writes fail, such as RAID-based file systems
> - file systems that make snapshots, such as Network Appliance's NFS
>        server
> - file systems that cache in temporary locations, such as NFS version
>        3 clients
> - compressed file systems
>
> In the case of ext3 file systems, the above disclaimer applies (and
>          shred is thus of limited effectiveness) only in data=journal mode,
>          which journals file data in addition to just metadata.  In both the
>          data=ordered (default) and data=writeback modes, shred works as
>          usual.  Ext3 journaling modes can be changed by adding the
>          data=something option to the mount options for a particular file
>          system in the /etc/fstab file, as documented in the mount man page
>          (man mount).

You can also take a look at [`shred.c`](https://github.com/wertarbyte/coreutils/blob/master/src/shred.c).

Comment: I am on a Windows 7/10 Dual-Boot system(s).

Comment: @AidanCodeX Sorry then. Please add appropriate tags and notes to your question.

Comment: I thought I did.  Which would you recommend?